# Combining Shapes for Laser Cutting and Etching

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, laser-cutting

HELP! I would like to add the black circle to the center of the flower. The red strokes are cut lines for the laser. The black is etch.  I need the black circle to merge with the flower, eliminating the red strokes behind the circle while keeping the cut lines that remain visible. Advice?

[image: Flower of Life with center]

Comment: What do you mean with "merge"? What's the expected visual result for the merged shapes?

Comment: Thank you for the request for clarification. My hope is to have the black circle (which signifies "etch") in the center of the flower with the shapes combined into one where the red lines behind the circle are no longer a component. Does that make sense?

Comment: So you don't wanna merge, you want to either cut or hide the red lines. Then what's wrong with just moving the black circle on top of the red lines?? I don't get what is the difficulty you're having.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the black circle suggests the following:

Simply remove the cutting lines in the middle. Insert a new shape, if you want some etches to the new solid area in the middle. I inserted some random lines to show, what I mean.

[image]